# Using subtype parameters when overriding Java methods

Tags: java, type-inference

I am thinking about writing a `Monoid` "type class" in Java. For instance,

```
interface Monoid<A> {
  Monoid<A> mappend(Monoid<A> ma);
}
```

However, if you want your own `List` to be a `Monoid`. You cannot `override` the `mappend` to `List<A> mapppend(List<A> la);`. The problem is that the parameter should be contra-variant. One brutal force way is to declare `mappend` as following:

```
Function<? extends Monoid<A>, ? extends Monoid<A>> mappend();
```

After experimenting a while, I figured the following:

```
interface X<A, Y extends X<?,?>> {
    Y f(Y y);
}

interface Z<A> extends X<A,Z<A>> {
    @Override Z<A> f(Z<A> za);
}
```

But it is not a general solution (for maybe `Applicative` or `Monad`):

```
interface X<A, Y extends X<?,?>> {
    Y f(Y y);
    <B> Y g(Function<A,Y> ay);
}

interface Z<A> extends X<A,Z<?>> {
    @Override Z<A> f(Z<?> za);
    @Override <B> Z<B> g(Function<A, Z<?>> ay);
}
```

`@Override <B> Z<B> g(Function<A, Z<?>> ay);` is the best I can do for `bind`.

Is there any way to get a `@Override <B> Z<B> g(Function<A, Z<B>> ay);`?